# Finding uncertainty, reduced chi-square for a gaussian fit in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gaussian, lmfit

I tried computing the standard errors for my data points for a Gaussian fit. I want to know how to calculate the errors and obtain the uncertainty. I want to compute the value of the reduced (chi-squared). Any suggestions would help. any suggestions and help in correcting the residual(p,x,y) would really help.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy import asarray as ar,exp
#reading the x,y,z values from the respective csv files
xData = []
yData = []
path = r'C:\Users\angel\OneDrive\Documents\CSV_FILES_NV_LAB\1111 x 30.csv'
with open(path, "r") as f_in:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in)
    next(reader)  # skip headers

    for line in reader:
        try:
            float_1, float_2=float(line[0]),float(line[1])
            xData.append(float_1)
            yData.append(float_2)
        except ValueError:
            continue
#printing the columns of the csv files and storing as an array
print(xData)
print(yData)
#plot the data points
plt.plot(xData,yData,'bo',label='experimental_data')
plt.show()
#define the function we want to fit the plot into
# Define the Gaussian function
n = len(xData)
xData=np.array(xData)
yData=np.array(yData)
mean = sum(xData*yData)/sum(yData)
sigma = np.sqrt(sum(yData*(xData-mean)**2)/sum(yData))
def Gauss(x,I0,x0,sigma,Background):
    return I0*exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))+Background

#popt,pcov = curve_fit(Gauss,xData,yData,p0=[1,mean,sigma, 0.0])
#calculating error methods

################################################################################
def residual(p,x,y):
    return Gaussian(x,*p)-y
initGuess=[1,1,1]
popt,pcov,infodict,mesg,ier=optimize.least_squares(residual,initGuess,args=[x,y],full_output=True)
s_sq = (infodict['fvec']**2).sum()/ (N-n)
#####################################################################################
print(popt)
plt.plot(xData,yData,'b+:',label='data')
plt.plot(xData,Gauss(xData,*popt),'ro:',label='fit')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Gaussian_Fit')
plt.xlabel('x-axis')
plt.ylabel('PL Intensity')
plt.show()
```

Sample input data:

```
xData=[
    -7.66e-06, -7.6e-06, -7.53e-06, -7.46e-06, -7.4e-06,
    -7.33e-06, -7.26e-06, -7.19e-06
]
yData=[
    17763.0, 2853.0, 3694.0, 4203.0, 4614.0, 4984.0,
    5080.0, 7038.0, 6905.0
]
```

Output Error:

```
popt,pcov,infodict,mesg,ier=optimize.least_squares(
    residual,initGuess,args=[x,y],full_output=True
)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined.
```

Comment: What do you mean by better..? More correct, more efficient, neater code..? What's wrong with what you have already? Can you include some sample input data plus outputs?

Comment: Given you have working code and you are only seeking to improve, It seems to me this question is more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Readable code always helps.  Like, the error you are getting is

```
popt,pcov,infodict,mesg,ier=optimize.least_squares(residual,initGuess,args=[x,y],full_output=True) 
NameError: name 'x' is not defined.
```

pretty much is telling you that 'x' is not defined.  Perhaps you meant 'xData'?

I recommend starting with the easier-to-use `lmfit`. With that, a fit to Gaussian data in a CSV file might look like this:

```
from pandas import read_csv
from lmfit.models import GaussianModel
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

dframe = read_csv('peak.csv')
xdata = dframe.to_numpy()[:, 0]
ydata = dframe.to_numpy()[:, 1]

model = GaussianModel()
params = model.guess(ydata, x=xdata)
result = model.fit(ydata, params, x=xdata)

print(f'Chi-square = {result.chisqr:.4f}, Reduced Chi-square = {result.redchi:.4f}')

print(result.fit_report())

plt.plot(xdata, ydata, label='data')
plt.plot(xdata, result.best_fit, label='best fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

That `print(result.fit_report())` will print out a something like this:

```
[[Model]]
    Model(gaussian)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 21
    # data points      = 101
    # variables        = 3
    chi-square         = 7.60712520
    reduced chi-square = 0.07762373
    Akaike info crit   = -255.189553
    Bayesian info crit = -247.344192
[[Variables]]
    amplitude:  30.5250840 +/- 0.31978873 (1.05%) (init = 40.626)
    center:     9.22348190 +/- 0.01498559 (0.16%) (init = 9.3)
    sigma:      1.23877032 +/- 0.01498552 (1.21%) (init = 1.3)
    fwhm:       2.91708114 +/- 0.03528820 (1.21%) == '2.3548200*sigma'
    height:     9.83051253 +/- 0.10298786 (1.05%) == '0.3989423*amplitude/max(1e-15, sigma)'
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(amplitude, sigma) =  0.577
```